# Зависает изображение при переподклюении второго монитора. Linux

Tags: linux, archlinux, nvidia, display

Ноутбук ThinkPad W520 c NVIDIA Quadro 1000M.

Видеодрайвер NVIDIA.

Монитор подключен к DisplayPort.

Суть проблемы: При старте системы успешно обнаруживаются два монитора и все прекрасно работает. При отключении внешнего монитора, и обратном его включении картинка на втором мониторе застывает. При этом система успешно продолжает работать, открывает на этом мониторе приложения и я могу их хоткеями переместить на другой монитор, однако картинка больше не меняется. Монитор заново начинает работать при перезапуске (перезагрузке) иксов, либо при переподключении монитора в nvidia-settings.

Arandr прекрасно видит монитор, и говорит что он активно работает (хотя картинка зависла).

В чем может быть проблема? И как ее решить?

P.S. Драйвер Intel поставить не могу, так как DisplayPort "вшит" в видеокарту Nvidia. А стандартный драйвер ядра не позволяет исправить ужасный тиринг.

Comment: Перестать пользоваться проприетарщиной? Дрова-то какие? Проприетарные или nouvea?

Comment: Мне не принципиально проприетарщина это или нет. Вы, видимо, невнимательно читаете вопрос. Там и драйвер обозначен и проблема. Если Вы говорите об использование открытых драйверов, то подскажите как на них убрать тирринг.

Answer (score 0):

Я попробовал xrandr, сделал себе алиас:

```
alias DISPL='xrandr --output HDMI --off && xrandr --output HDMI --auto --right-of DVI'
```

Где гаснет монитор по имени HDMI справа.
Узнать имена моников можно:

```
$ xrandr --listmonitors
Monitors: 2
 0: <параметры>  <имя>
 1: <параметры>  <имя>
```

По крайней мере, мне помогло, при зависании я запускаю скрипт и продолжаю работать, правда, окна приложений надо переносить потом.